# Is it wrong to append a comment to question?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34218879/can-someone-help-me-to-find-out-why-i-get-an-500-error-in-this-code-i-am-a-begin) the OP posted a question, without any error messages. After asking about the error messages he provided it, in the comments. Since this error message can be useful in order to answer the question, [I suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10522888), moving his error message to the question.

To my surprise, my suggestion was rejected 3 to 1. Stating that

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit.

which in my opinion, was not the case.

I am a bit clueless about why it got rejected. Is it wrong to to append an error message of the OP him-/herself, to the question?

Comment: The reviewers just blundered. Your edit summary should have been quite sufficient.

Comment: Reasonable edit, certainly, keep in mind that reviewers don't usually spend enough time on a review to see that this came from a comment. And your comment on the edit wasn't exactly crystal.  I recommend that next time you say something like "Included important comment from the OP in the question".

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: It is so sad to see that this page has so many bad reviewers. And Hans Passants comment *"keep in mind that reviewers don't usually spend enough time on a review to see that this came from a comment"* is right and shows that these reviewers are incapable of doing proper reviews.

Comment: What Hans said. You _need_ to be more specific in your edit comments. Many reviewers don't bother looking at the original question page, so they don't see the question's comments, they only see your edit suggestion & edit comment. A better edit comment would be "Added error message which was posted in comments by OP".

Comment: Also, when suggesting edits _please_ try to fix up all of the basic flaws like spelling & grammar errors and poor formatting. Reviewers may reject your edit if they see that you haven't fixed such basic flaws. Yes, it's good to improve faulty posts, but do a complete job of it so somebody else doesn't have to come along and do further improvements. Consider: if 2 <2000 rep users submit edit suggestions to one post that's a total of 8 people's time and energy being used to fix that post.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your suggested edit was perfectly okay, and in fact very welcome. Without error message the question is somewhat useless, and one cannot depend on crucial information being hidden in comments. Most likely the reviewers didn't have enough context to see the usefulness of the edit (e.g. because they came from the queue) and it looked too suspicious for someone to edit such substantial information into a post.

Answer (score 12):

Your edit was largely correct, although lacking in other areas (removing noise, spelling, clearer problem statement). I made an edit to the question now appending the error provided by OP in the comment. Please for future reference try to improve all parts of a question when editing.

I do not believe rejecting the edit was correct by the reviewers, especially not for the reason given above.

Comment: Agreed. The reviewers should have hit Improve Edit. The content and intent were good, but the formatting and grammar (even within the added content) were abysmal.

Answer (score 3):

Everything you did was correct and like the other answers it should have been approved.  One thing I would have done differently if I was you was to fix the incorrect English from the comment that you added to the answer.

> Oke i got this error right know:

Should have at least been

> Okay I got this error right now:

And could have even been improved to something along the lines of

> This is the error message I am getting currently:

I can understand you not wanting to change what the OP said but correct spelling and grammar are something we want on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Another, in my opinion better, way to handle this would have been to tell the OP he/she should add the error message to the question. Then the OP would have the opportunity to learn how SO works.

Of course if the OP doesn't do it in reasonable time, or if there are other issues, an edit is appropriate.

I think the reviewers misinterpreted "I have this error" as meaning *you* have this error, instead of *the OP* has this error. There are sometimes edits from people that have a similar issue and try to "take over" a Q&A with an edit. A clear description of your edit could have prevented this.